# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function with CHARINDEX within SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring, charindex

Column `[LOG_Description]` returns

`OK Return value 1 RV1>Success<RV1Return value 2 RV2>test.user@domain.com<RV2`

I want to extract the email address.

Executing

`SUBSTRING(LOG_Description, CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)+4, CHARINDEX('<RV2',LOG_Description) - CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)-4)`

returns an `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function` error.

I checked length of the email address itself using `CHARINDEX('<RV2',LOG_Description) - CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)-4` which equals `24`.

Then I substituted the third argument of the SUBSTRING function, i.e. `CHARINDEX('<RV2',LOG_Description) - CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)-4` with 24 and I do get the correct extraction of the e-mail address `test.user@domain.com.`

I cannot figure out why it's working with the direct value but not with the CHARINDEX function within SUBSTRING when the CHARINDEX function returns the correct value if executed outside of SUBSTRING.

Any help is appreciated.

The complete initial query is as follows:

```
SELECT LOG_Description,

-- SUBSTRING(LOG_Description, CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)+4, 24),
SUBSTRING(LOG_Description, CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)+4, CHARINDEX('<RV2',LOG_Description) - CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)-4), -- this is the one that should work but throws the error
-- CHARINDEX('<RV2',LOG_Description) - CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)-4

FROM
(SELECT LOG_Description
FROM dbo.WFLogs
WHERE LOG_WFDID = 2000
AND LOG_Description LIKE '%RV2>%'
) logEntry
```

Upon suggestion to use `NULLIF()` with `CHARINDEX()` I adapted the query to:

```
SELECT LOG_Description,

-- SUBSTRING(LOG_Description, CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)+4, 24),
SUBSTRING(LOG_Description, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)+4,0), NULLIF(CHARINDEX('<RV2',LOG_Description),0) - NULLIF(CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)-4,0))
-- CHARINDEX('<RV2',LOG_Description) - CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)-4

FROM
(SELECT LOG_Description
FROM dbo.WFLogs
WHERE LOG_WFDID = 2000
AND LOG_Description LIKE '%RV2>%'
) logEntry
```

The difference between the original query and the one with `NULLIF()`is that the latter does not throw the error but also doesn't strip the last `<RV2` tag:

```
test.user@domain.com<RV2
```

I tried changing the `-4` at the end of the query but that doesn't change anything. -2, -8 produces the above mentioned output.
Changing it to a positive value, e.g. +4 throws the error again.

Another suggestion was to use `CORSS APPLY`

```
select LOG_WFDID, LOG_TSInsert, LOG_Description, IsNull(Substring(LOG_Description, s+4, e - s-4),' ') EmailAddress
from dbo.WFLogs

cross apply (
    values(NullIf(CharIndex('RV2>',LOG_Description),0), NullIf(CharIndex('<RV2',LOG_Description),0))
)x(s,e)

-- WHERE LOG_WFDID = 2000
-- AND LOG_TSInsert > DATEADD(DAY,-3,GetDate())
-- AND LOG_Description LIKE '%RV2>%'
ORDER BY LOG_TSInsert DESC
```

This kind of works. It still throws the `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` error but returns columns with email addresses. However, it also returns columns that don't have the  tags in them (didn't occurr to me before records without exist).

So I was trying to use `WHERE` to narrow down the results but `WHERE` in conjunction with `CROSS APPLY` doesn't seem to work. Uncommenting the three `WHERE` (above) only yields the `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` error.

Comment: Your string manipulation works fine for the value as provided. It's probably not working for other data in your table, for example if you had a string that was missing the closing <RV2 you would get the error you are receiving. You need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I also removed the *mysql* tag - you have tagged *tsql* and are using *charindex* which contradicts *mysql*

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't know how to give a more minimal example but I will add the entire query. Every column value contains the RV1><RV1 & RV2><RV2 tags. You should be able to exactly copy my values and be able to repro the issue. Is that not the case?

Comment: So`select * from table where LOG_Description not like '%<RV2'` and for other expected tags all return no rows?

Comment: What if you use `AND LOG_Description LIKE '%RV2>%<RV2'`

Comment: *You should be able to exactly copy my values and be able to repro the issue. Is that not the case?* - yes that's not the case, [your example works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=257695023308ab106fe191f1433d08f1), which is why you need to provide an example that does *not* work -

Comment: Use `NULLIF(CHARINDEX...., 0)` to remove incorrect data

Comment: @Stu, sorry but I'm not able to provide a non-working example. Everything outside of SQL Management Studio without my db + table does work like the example you've provided. It might be the way spaces are shown/handled and exist/not exist.

Comment: @Charlieface, I amended my original post with the results of your proposal, please have a look.

Comment: Looks like you're doing it wrong `NULLIF(CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description),0)+4` not `NULLIF(CHARINDEX('RV2>',LOG_Description)+4,0)`

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following for a working solution?

Here I'm using `cross apply` and `values` to simplify the expression to calculate the start and end tag positions:

```
with t as ( /* sample data */
    select 'OK Return value 1 RV1>Success<RV1Return value 2 RV2>test.user@domain.com<RV2' as LOG_Description union all
    select 'OK Return value 1 RV1>Success<RV1Return value 2 RV2>test.user@domain.com<RbadV2' union all
    select 'OK Return value 1 RV1>Success<RV1Return value 2 RV2>test.user@domain.com<0RV2' union all
    select 'OK Return value 1 RV1>Success<RV1Return value 2 RV2>test2.user@domain2.com<RV2' union all
    select 'OK Return value 1 RV1>Success<RV1Return value 2 V2>test.user@domain.com<0V2'
)
select IsNull(Substring(LOG_Description, s+4, e - s-4),'') EmailAddress
from t
cross apply (
    values(NullIf(CharIndex('RV2>',LOG_Description),0), NullIf(CharIndex('<RV2',LOG_Description),0))
)x(s,e)
```

Comment: Thanks. It kind of works. Can you please see my amended post down at the bottom?

Comment: @colonel_claypoo Can you amend [this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=773259277027d51c7574aba13f3afb33) to reproduce the error?

Comment: So I couldn`t repro the error but what I did in despair is create new SQL entries and for whatever reason now it`s working as intended. I have to speak to my colleagues whether they changed anything in the way those records get created. Thank you very much, I appreciate you help Stu.